# react navigation, get name of nested route

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a nested drawer navigator below, I am using a custom component in the header:

```
header: props => {
    return <DrawerHeader {...props} />;
},
```

When I try and access from props the current route in my header, like below, the title is `undefined`, how can I get the current route?

```
  render() {
    const {
      navigation,
      videos,
      search: {term},
      scene: {
        route: {routeName: title}, // undefined
      },
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
```

Navigator:

```
function DrawerStack() {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator>
            <Drawer.Screen
                name="VideoEpisodesScreen"
                component={VideoEpisodesScreen}
            />
            <Drawer.Screen name="TestYourselfScreen" component={TestYourselfScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="MyResultsScreen" component={MyResultsScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="AboutScreen" component={AboutScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="TestsScreen" component={TestsScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen
                name="BookmarkedVideosScreen"
                component={BookmarkedVideosScreen}
            />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
}

export default function AppNavigator() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Home"
                    component={HomeScreen}
                    options={stackOptions}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Drawer"
                    component={DrawerStack}
                    options={drawerOptions}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="MyResultsScreen"
                    component={MyResultsScreen}
                    options={options}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Funnily enough I had the exact same problem and I found your question after it was just an hour old. Essentially the problem is that React Navigation will only give you the current route of the navigator containing the header. If you have a nested navigator, you won't be able to get it.

It looks like this is somewhat intentional, but I've found that by manually querying the state of the navigator, you can drill down to the "deepest" navigator route. Note that while this works for react-navigation 5, it may not work in the future.

You can iteratively query the nested state like this:

```js
const state = navigation.dangerouslyGetState();
let actualRoute = state.routes[state.index];

while (actualRoute.state) {
    actualRoute = actualRoute.state.routes[actualRoute.state.index];
}
```

Note that this is extremely brittle, but it seems to work good enough for my use cases. You should consider creating an issue/feature request on the react-navigation repository for supporting this use case officially.

Comment: `actualRoute.state.index` can be `undefined` so you need to check it as well

Comment: [`useNavigationState`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state/) hook is now available - advantage is that it doesn't have word _dangerous_ in it as well as that it causes rerender when navigation state changes...

Comment: for `v6` use `navigation.getState()`

Answer (score 2):

React Navigation v6 solution:

A nested route object can be discovered through parent Screen listeners. It's given in a callback argument, and can be passed to getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute to get the route name. In the example shown below, I chose to utilize it during the event 'state' (whenever state changes in the nested stack), but you can use it elsewhere if you want.

```
<Screen 
  listeners={({ route }) => ({
    state: () => {
      const subRoute = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route)
      // Your logic here //
    }
  })}
/>
```

Answer (score -3):

I think in react-navigation 5, you can access route from `this.props`

`const { route } = this.props;`